# Can you use "auth and capture" with the Stripe "embedded payment form"?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment-processing

Is it possible to use the "authorization then capture" process ([see here](https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-authorize-and-capture))   without building a full custom checkout process on the front-end?

I would like to use the standard checkout button ([see here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial)) and still be able to set the capture=false parameter.  Is it possible or am I dreaming ?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charging a customer with Stripe is a two-step process, involves a front-end checkout form and a server backend to make the charge. The `capture` parameter only comes into play at the backend --- it's never part of your Checkout form so you can definitely use a simple button.

Step 1: You collect a customer's credit card information with a Checkout or Stripe.js form, which is then sent to Stripe. In return Stripe sends back a `token` that you can use to charge the card.

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js

Step 2: You take this `token` and pass it to your backend, then tell Stripe to make a charge request, or save it to a customer. You will need to setup an endpoint on your server to handle this.

https://stripe.com/docs/charges

It is at this stage where you pass `capture=False` in your charge request.

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you so much!